# .docx file returning wrong file type

Tags: php, file, file-upload, mime-types

When I echo the file type of a docx file, it seems to be cut off. Does any one has any idea where I might be wrong?

$strInputFile = "test.docx;

echo $file_type = $_FILES[$strInputFile]["type"]; // gives application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.word

Thanks

Comment: That looks like the correct format to me ...

Comment: For anyone curious what it *should* be (like myself), it's `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Comment: For some reason it's been cut off at 50 characters. Odd...

Comment: its not even getting pulled from the database to get cut off.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file type to compare was getting saved to the database and it was getting cut of from there. Increased the field value size in db and its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the fault of PHP - but the client used to upload the file. Checking the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) shows that the ['type'] value is set by the client.

An alternative is to pass through [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) or [finfo_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) in PHP 5.3 or newer - these use a 'magic' file on your server to determine the file's MIME type.

Note, that even this is not infallible, as the functions search for fingerprints in the files to determine the MIME type (example, I've often had CSS files detected as C# because I had a /* comment at the top of the file).

Comment: from where is $_FILES['userfile']['type'] coming from? sorry, i'm not an expert in file uploading. It was working fine. One fine morning, it stopped working.

Comment: It'll be coming from the browser that you uploaded the file to your server with.